# Java Spring controller fetching from React fetch()

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-restcontroller

I use React for fronted + Java Spring controllers that have some endpoints for backend. But for some of endpoints I have response with React features and for some without React features. I am new with React part, so I suppose that I am missing some principles of fetch(). Please help me to understand and fix.

**Case 1**
App.js code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App () {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hello')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(message => {
                setMessage(message);
            });
    },[])
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="">
                <h1>React is here!</h1>
                <h2 className="App-title">{message}</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Java controller code:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
public class BasicController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Everyone !";
    }
}
```

As a result I see "React is here!" + "Hello Everyone !" with according style string on *localhost:8080*. So I see that the backend returns value and React also works with it.

But if I go to *localhost:8080/api/v1/hello*, I see only "Hello Everyone !" string without React features. So the backend returns value, but React doesn't work.

Why, if I am fetching this particular endpoint? **- Question 1**

Actually, the same result if I use

```
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1")
```

- without the first /

**Case 2**
I have the same App.js but change fetch(URL) to

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080')
```

And I add a new Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class StartPageController {

    @GetMapping()
    public String startPage() {
        return "Start page"; 
    }

}
```

If I go to *localhost:8080*, that I am fetching I see only "Start page" string without React features. So the backend returns value, but React doesn't work.

Why, if it is the simplest option for endpoint path and even more complex fetch worked as I mentioned above? **- Question 2**

**Case 3**

As it seems that I have some issue with "/" endpoint, I decided to check how the Case 1 endpoint will work if I leave StartPageController from the Case 2. So I just return back url:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hello'),
```

but leave both controllers.

As a result, for now, I see that React features doesn't work either for *localhost:8080*, or *localhost:8080/api/v1/hello* (the last one actually as in Case 1). Only backend values "Start page" or "Hello Everyone !" return for all mentioned endpoints. Without React.

So it seems that the "/" endpoint from StartPageController doesn't work with React by itself and also doesn't allow to work other more complex endpoints as a root endpoint.

**So 2 questions as a result:**

1. What is the issue with some particular paths - Case 1?
2. What is the issue with "/" endpoint - Case 2 and 3?

How I run Spring boot + React - I make a .jar file by Maven, where I collect both parts for frontend and backend by .pom build configurations. And I run the .jar in Intellij IDEA. I need to do it this way because I want to deploy .jar later on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand this code first :

```
@RestController
   @CrossOrigin
   @RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
   public class BasicController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Everyone !";
      }
   }
```

Probably your backend server is running at port **8080** and if you hit this url `localhost:8080/api/v1/hello` , it gives the output as "Hello Everyone" which you've returned from the controller right ? How do you expect to get React Part when you hit this endpoint ? When you run `localhost:8080/api/v1/hello` this is Spring Part [Java part] and not the react part. If you use this endpoint from the react app or any client you'll always get "Hello Everyone" as per your logic, same applies for the StartPage controller as well.

Try to run your react application, if you're fetching correctly, you'll see the backend part used with front end part. It's as simple as that.

See which port the react application is using ? It's probably `localhost:3000` see if it's working or not. There, you'll see the result.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: As I mentioned in the Case 1 React part can works fine(!) with my backend part together with current settings. So I've checked that React part running and Spring part running at the same time. From logs I see that at this moment Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) (so not 8000). As for React port 3000, as I understand it works together with 8080 due to @CrossOrigin annotation in controller that helps to avoid CORS issue. And yes, it is correct that backend endpoints always return what they should. But the question is why React works with them for some cases(url paths) and for some not.

Comment: So I mean why it works fine in Case 1 when React fetches url path /api/v1/hello that I put in fetch() and doesn't do the same with url path / in Case 2 ? I have backend controller for both these endpoints. And nothing but url path in fetch changes.

Comment: And the second question is why just by adding StartPageController with / endpoint I ruin the Case 1 (its React part) work that worked fine before the adding?

Comment: Have you tried fetching ```http://localhost:8080/``` from the react application ?  If it doesn't work, can you check the console or error log from the running application ? Kindly paste the logs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your support, yes, I've tried to do it and it fine when I run app and React separately as usual, but after maven clean/install it doesn't work correctly inside .jar. I've made some changes in my project and published it on GitHub https://github.com/AlexCodePlace/mywebsiteproject . Please, pull it, it to be sure that we are on the same page. The important aspect - it also should work by running .jar after maven clean/install, because I need to publish the project on AWS EBS and it will be running on Java platform - so the whole app (Java+React) on one port 8080, as I understand.

Comment: I am working with this issue, so maybe something will change in my commits at the moment when you'll take a look into my repo. So feel free to make pull request there if you want to change smth or text here what configurations I need to use. My main goals are - 1st to run app with fetching different endpoints like /, /hello and others and 2nd to make it in .jar for next deploy. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @rsnlpn kindly check your developer console  when you run and try to fetch data with the help of the react application  and post the logs you get there. This way I can help if the endpoint you're hitting isn't correct.